# Is it possible to turn firebase's image upload "uploadTask.on" listener into a promise?

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, firebase-storage

I am using firebase and notice that most of the method's are returning promises, but in the documentation this one is not. Is it possible to change this into a promise?

```
uploadTask.on(
    'state_changed',
    function(snapshot) {
        const progress = snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes * 100;
        console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
    },
    function(error) {
        alert(error);
    },
    function() {
        const downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
        console.log(downloadURL);
    }
);
```

Comment: No. Promises, by definition, wait for a value that will be resolved *once*. The `.on` listener will trigger as many times as the data updates.

Comment: @Sidney See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want some promise to resolve when the upload is complete, use this generalized pattern:

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // whenever the work is complete and successful
    resolve()
    // or, whenever the work finishes with an error
    reject()
})
```

[According to the API docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask#on), for a Cloud Storage for Firebase UploadTask, your `on` handler will receive an a callback for "complete", as your fourth argument.  So you can modify it like this:

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   uploadTask.on(
    'state_changed',
    function(snapshot) {
      const progress = snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes * 100;
      console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
    },
    function(error) {
      reject(error);  // added this line
      alert(error);
    },
    function() {
      const downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
      console.log(downloadURL);
      resolve();  // added this line
    }
  );
});
```

You can see that I added calls to `resolve` and `reject` in your code, now embedded in a closure inside a Promise.